# Javascript: How to update via DOM element?

Tags: javascript

My function below need to update a certain row value (Fruit Name) when the first Select has been changed. How can I update the last <"input"> element? I don't know what is the correct DOM property to use.

I need to use DOM so I don't need to set id on the tags.

HTML

```
<table>
   <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Option:
             <select onChange="updateValue(this);">
                <option>A</option>
                <option>B</option>
             </select>
          </td>
          <td>Quantity:
             <select>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
             </select>
          </td>
          <td>Shipping Address:
            <input type="text"/>
          </td>
          <td>Fruit Name:
            <input type="text"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function updateValue(obj){
   var _input = obj.parentNode.nextSibling.firstChild;
   _input.innerText = 'Apple';  

}
```

Comment: There is no [input type *textbox*](http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#sec-states-of-the-type-attribute). *innerText* is an IE proprietary property that is not supported in all browsers, and inputs do not have any *innerText* anyway, they have a *value*.

Answer (score 1):

`firstElementChild & lastElementChild` is to get html element only not a text(html string).So it is more better to get specific element!

```
function updateValue(obj){
   var _input = obj.parentNode.parentNode.lastElementChild.firstElementChild;
   _input.value = 'Apple';      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a minor change in your HTML code.Add a class which will help to recognize which input to update. Use `parentNode` twice to move up to `tr`. Then use the `className` to find the `input` which you want to update

```
<td>Fruit Name:
            <input type="text" class="fruitClass"/>
          </td>
```

JS Change

```
function updateValue(obj){
  var _input = obj.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("fruitClass")[0]
   _input.value = 'Apple';  

}
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kavxatro/4/)

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/kavxatro/6/

```
function updateValue(obj){
   // get the last TD of this TR
   var _input = obj.parentNode.parentNode.lastChild;
   // make sure we are on the TD. If not, get the previous object.
   if (typeof _input.tagName == 'undefined') _input = _input.previousSibling;
   // get the input inside the TD
   _input = _input.lastChild;
   // make sure we are on the input. If not, get the previous object.
   if (typeof _input.tagName == 'undefined') _input = _input.previousSibling;
   // change the input value
   _input.value = 'Apple';  
}
```

The first time you use `parentNode` you get the parent of the `SELECT`, that is the `TD`.

The second `parentNode` gets the parent of this `TD`, that is the `TR`.

You can use `lastChild` to get the last element inside this `TR`, that is the last `TD`.

And since you only have one element inside that `TD`, then either `firstChild` or `lastChild` should get you the `input` object.

To change the value of an input field you use `value`, not `innerText`.

Also there is no HTML form type `textbox`. If you want a one-line input form then `text` is the type you should use.

```
      <td>Fruit Name:
        <input type="text"/>
      </td>
```

Comment: It is throwing error Cannot set property 'value' of null.Check this jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/kavxatro/2/

Comment: True, lastChild seems to take the last line break. It works here https://jsfiddle.net/kavxatro/5/ with `obj.parentNode.parentNode.lastChild.previousSibling.lastChild.previousSibling;`. I'm not sure this is going to work the same way in every browser though. You may have to do some checking as well.